# 'Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update' prompt on gui but terminal says everything is up to date. What is it? Is it safe to install?

Tags: linux, debian, boot, upgrade, firmware

While using my debian system I got an important update prompt from gnome. When I opened it what I saw was an update I've never seen before. Here is the entire description.

```
Device Firmware
Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update
83 > 217

Version 217:
This updates the dbx to the latest release from Microsoft which adds insecure versions of grub and shim to the list of forbidden signatures due to multiple discovered security updates.

Before installing the update, fwupd will check for any affected executables in the ESP and will refuse to update if it finds any boot binaries signed with any of the forbidden signatures. If the installation fails, you will need to update shim and grub packages before the update can be deployed.

Once you have installed this dbx update, any DVD or USB installer images signed with the old signatures may not work correctly. You may have to temporarily turn off secure boot when using recovery or installation media, if new images have not been made available by your distribution.

Version 211:
This updates the dbx to the latest release from Microsoft which adds insecure versions of grub and shim to the list of forbidden signatures due to multiple discovered security updates.

Version 190:
This updates the dbx to the latest release from Microsoft which adds insecure versions of grub and shim to the list of forbidden signatures due to multiple discovered security updates.
```

I wanted to check what packages were to be changed via terminal so I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`. However `apt-get` says there is nothing to upgrade.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

In the past when gnome notified me about 'important updates' I could always check in terminal and it was always a restart-requiring kernel update. However this update is visible on gui but not on terminal. What is it? Is it safe to update? I am worried because it talks about booting and I do not want any of my installation drives or debian itself to become unbootable.

Below is my operating system.

```
uname -a
```

```
Linux debian 5.10.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a *firmware update*, and those are handled by the `fwupdmgr` utility, not as package updates.

See `fwupdmgr get-devices` to see what firmware elements can be updated by `fwupdmgr`, and `fwupdmgr get-updates` to see a list of available updates.

If you want to update the firmware to the latest available, run `fwupdmgr update`.

In this specific case, this dbx update is related to [the BootHole vulnerability](https://eclypsium.com/2021/04/14/boothole-how-it-started-how-its-going/) published in April 2021. Since `apt-get upgrade` shows you are fully up-to-date, it means your GRUB bootloader and Secure Boot shim have already been updated to the non-vulnerable versions signed with a new Secure Boot key, and so the old vulnerable versions can safely be blacklisted, which is exactly what this `dbx` update does.

Since this vulnerability required Debian and related distributions to update their Secure Boot keys, any Debian/Ubuntu boot media that dates from before April 2021 will no longer boot in UEFI mode with Secure Boot enabled on your system once you install this firmware update. If you need to use old installation media, you might have to disable Secure Boot.

If you want, you could compare the contents of the update to the [revocation list published by UEFI.org](https://uefi.org/revocationlistfile).

Answer (score 0):

Leave it to microsoft to screw up my Dell Ubuntu system.  I presume this is only for dual boot windows machines? Why would a Microsoft boot loader be on my Ubuntu machine (it is a dell factory-installed Ubuntu)..

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please note, this isn't a discussion forum but Q&A site. The "Your Answer" -box you used to post this is reserved strictly, as the title implies, for posting answers to questions. Please take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and review some older questions with [accepted answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how the site works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/441108)